# WPF button mouseover or hover change rectangle background

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mouseover

I want to change a rectangle's (or else's) background/imagesource or visibility when the cursor is over a specified button.

Comment: Great! Have you tried anything? An `EventTrigger` perhaps?

Comment: You need to search for similar questions before posting a new one.

Comment: @Abdullah
If you found one please show it

Comment: @BradleyDotNET
Yes, I tried, a created a custom style for my buttons in this window but I have four buttons and each one should change different background for the rectangle when the mouse is over them.

But I am not very good at xaml, maybe I do it wrong.

Comment: I copied your question title, pasted it into google, and found [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202323/change-rectangle-background-on-mouse-hover)

Comment: @Abdullah
Then I clearly don't know ho to use google right, shame on me :( I searched for almost anything but I thought my problem with the rectangle and the buttons is too specific to try and I found only solutions for change background of the object where the mouse is. Sorry again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I toggle a TextBlock's visibility in a DataTrigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422287/how-can-i-toggle-a-textblocks-visibility-in-a-datatrigger)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code changes rectangle background when mouse is over button.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="200"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="200"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Width="200" Height="100" Content="Hover over me..." x:Name="btn">           
        </Button>
        <Rectangle Height="200" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="Rect1">
            <Rectangle.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=btn, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Blue" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Rectangle.Style>            
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>    
</Window>
```

Comment: Thank you, combined with Abdullah's hint it is working!:)